# Converting ampersand to and using CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code that sanitizes post titles for saving the slug in my app:

```
$post_title = Sanitize::html($this->request->data['Post']['title'], array('remove'=>true, 'quotes' => ENT_NOQUOTES));
                $post_title = String::truncate($post_title, 50, array('exact'=>false,'html'=>false,'ending'=>''));
                $this->Post->saveField('slug', Inflector::slug($post_title));
```

**Just in case anyone brings it up. I know of sluggable plugin but prefer to do it manually!**

However ampersands are saved as 'amp' in the inflector. So I'm looking to convert '&' to 'and' before the inflection stage.

How would I do this in PHP? I've looked at the str_replace function. Would this be correct?

e.g. `str_replace('&','and',$post_title)` but what about the count parameter? Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_replace('&','and',$post_title)` is correct. You dont need the count parameter. This will replace all instances of `&` with `and`.

I guess you want to do this before you truncate the string, because obviously `and` takes more charactors.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for that. I guess I should of just gone ahead and tried it, but wondered if there was a better way of doing it.

Comment: Well I suppose they are saved as `&amp;` and not just `amp` and that is valid HTML aswel, so maybe you dont even need to change it?